# Primitive value returned from constructor will be lost

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function:

```
function CheckHidden(el){ return $(el).css('display')!='none' }
```

My IDE warns me that:

> *Primitive value returned from constructor will be lost when called with 'new'*

Actually when I call it like this:

```
var all = $("#catalog-body > div").filter(function(){return  CheckHidden(this)})
```

it doesn't work and doesn't reduce set of elements to unhidden ones.
Please explain to me the issue. I have a giant lack of knowledge.

Comment: There are multiple questions in one. Which one describes your problem best?

Comment: I'm not sure what IDE you're using, but this is specific to the IDE and not to JavaScript. If you have a method that you never instantiate with new then disregard the warning.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I ran into this warning myself and if you want to know the cause, it is because your IDE expect function names to start with a lowercase letter. Since your function is called CheckHidden with a capital C, it thinks it's a class declaration.

However, you should still use jQuery's :visible selector to fix your specific issue.

Comment: If you don't want to change your function name to lowercase, you can avoid the warning with a`/** * @returns {boolean} */` comment line above the function.

Answer (score 11):

If you create an object using the keyword `new` (as mentioned in the warning), JS returns an new instance of the object rather than the return value from the constructor.

A function like

```
function CheckHidden() {
    return false;
}
```

would return two different values, depending on how it is executed.

```
// "a" is boolean value
var a = CheckHidden();

// "a" is an object of type "CheckHidden"
var a = new CheckHidden();
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery actually has something like this built in. You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector. You can just do:

```
var all=$("#catalog-body > div").filter(':visible')
```

to get the visible elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull all elements which are visible, you can use [**jQuery's `:visible` selector**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
var all = $("#catalog-body > div:visible")
```

Conversely, if you want to pull all elements which are hidden, you can combine this with [jQuery's `:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("#catalog-body > div:not(:visible)")
```