# "Primitive value will be lost" warning in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

WebStorm marks the entire GUID method block as a warning of "Primitive value returned from the constructor will be lost when called with 'new'".

```
export const GUID = () => {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
};

export const GUID8 = () => {
    return GUID().substr(0, 8);
};

export const GUID4 = () => {
    return GUID().substr(0, 4);
};


export default GUID;
```

Any Idea why?

Source of the GUID method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/172815

Comment: Since you're not returning an object it is unclear to me why that is happening. Does it also happen if you don't use fat arrow functions? You might find this post helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468055/what-does-new-in-javascript-do-anyway

Comment: Yep, happens anyhow

Comment: It could be a weird IDE thing. Try renaming your functions to begin with lower case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338563/primitive-value-returned-from-constructor-will-be-lost