# When does a constructor function return `this` and when does it return what it has been told to return?

Tags: javascript

Look at this example. Two weird constructor functions are defined here. I say weird because both have return statements and don't return (implicitly) `this` as normally constructor functions do.

But what is strange is that... when called with the `new` operator...

1) C3 returns the newly constructed `this` object even though it has been told to return "ggg".
2) C2 returns what it has been told to return (not the `this` object).

Why this difference in the behavior? What is the conceptual difference between C2 and C3?

When does a constructor function return `this` and when does it return what it has been told to return?

```js
function C2() {
    this.a = 1;
    return {b: 2};
}
var c2 = new C2();
console.log(c2.a); //undefined
console.log(c2.b); //2
console.log(c2);   //{b:2}
```

```js
function C3() {
    this.a = 1;
    return "ggg";
}
var c3 = new C3();
console.log(c3.a); //1
console.log(c3);   //C3 {a: 1}
```

Comment: If the return type is an object, `new` will have no effect as the function will return that object

Comment: https://javascript.info/constructor-new#return-from-constructors

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the documentation for the new operator:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

> Returns `this` if the function doesn't return its own **object**.

In case of C3 you're not returning an object (strings are primitives), so 'this' is returned.

Answer (score 2):

> Constructor functions **always** return objects.

The above rule can't be violated, if you try to do so (return a primitive from a constructor), the default object (`this`) will be returned instead.

See more information in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26338563/8376184), [here](https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/return-values-with-the-new-operator/), and on [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/constructor-new#return-from-constructors).

This rule is also an *invariant* in Proxies, and therefore they'll even throw errors, when you try to do that:

```js
const p=new Proxy(function(){},{
  construct(){
    return 'ggg'
  }
})

new p() //TypeError: Construct trap on proxy must return an object
```